# Why does ngFor break focus on input when function is used to return array of objects

Tags: angular, focus, ngfor

Focus blocks input (you cant type anything) while iterate using *ngfor over array of objects returned by function. However the same works when array of objects is inside the template. What's the problem?

[image]

template

```
<!-- does not work -->
<div *ngFor="let d of testValues()">
  <input (focus)="testFocus($event)" type="text" />
</div>


<!-- works -->
<div *ngFor="let d of [{ a: 0 }, { a: 1 }]">
  <input (focus)="testFocus($event)" type="text" />
</div>
```

component

```
  testValues() {
    return [{ a: 0 }, { a: 1 }];
  }

  testFocus($event: FocusEvent) {
    console.log('focus ', $event);
  }
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fmkpcc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wild guess, but I'd  say that's because the `focus` event triggers a ChangeDetection.

With that change detection, your method `testValues()` will return a new set of values. So the input you clicked has been replaced with a new one and is no longer there.

---

Edit:
Confirmed this is it, the following code fixes it :

```
  private values =  [{ a: 0 }, { a: 1 }];


  testValues() {
    return this.values;
  }
```

Here, when the change detection happens, the value returned by the method is the same instance of your array, so the inputs stay the same.